# Phonegap plugin implements error, and does not work

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I have days trying to make a single notification, vibrate and the playBeep() functions in my android app using cordova phonegap

Can you guys help me?

The problem is that nothing is working on!
Plugins used:local-notifications, whitelist, dialogs, vibration, and device.

Here a part of the index and a part of js code
(cant paste index so im redacting it)

```
    <div id ="div"><img id="rojo" src = "rojo.png" onclick="playBeep()"/>
<img id="verde" src = "verde.png" onclick="vibrate()"/>
<img id="azul" src = "azul.png" onclick="showAlert()"/>
```

Then my js function

```
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
       // PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Empty
}

// Show a custom alert
//
function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'You are the winner!',  // message
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
    );
}

// Beep three times
//
function playBeep() {
    navigator.notification.beep(3);
}

// Vibrate for 2 seconds
//
function vibrate() {
    navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);
}
```

Comment: No. Its all wrong. Start with known working code. Try the ["hello world"](https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world) first.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 thats not a good afford by the way,.. Just finished my app thanks.